# Chartjs box plot with Y-axis negative values

Tags: chart.js, boxplot

The example I used:

https://jsbin.com/yekimavemu/2/edit?html,js,console,output

How can I build a box plot in chart-js with negative values on Y-axis?

I tried:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        max: 4,
        min: -4
      }
```

but I don't know where I can put this.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a modern plugin like [Chart.js Box and Violin Plot (GitHub)](https://github.com/datavisyn/chartjs-chart-box-and-violin-plot) instead of a hardly-readable workaround from a four year old version of chart.js [(Version 1.0.2)](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v1.0.2).